# Calculating power requirements of RGB LED strips

Tags: power-supply, led-strip

Is there any formula or rule of thumb for calculating power requirements of 'typical' RGB LED strips? Say x amps per # of lights? or are there too many other variables involved(specific make, etc).

Comment: See the datasheets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- There are way too many types of LED strips (*e.g. individually addressable or not, I2C, SPI or PWM interface, integrated current limiting resistors, ...*)
- A wide variety of LED chips are used in such strips (*5 mA, 20 mA, 500 mA or even 1 Ampere per color, and SMD 3528 through to high-power LED per color*), for any general rule of thumb to be applicable.
- Also, the number of LEDs in a strip is yet another variable.

In short, **there is no such thing as a "typical" RGB LED strip**.

An LED strip manufacturer will typically list rated power for the strip, that is the best recourse for determining power requirements.

Comment: thanks, other than the wiki, are you aware of any good LED strip 'primers' online?